# Spring seurity conflict `hibernate-validator`

Tags: spring, validation, security, notnull

pom.xml file already add dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

in custom bean "Car"

```
    @NotNull(message = "not null")
    private String price;
```

in controller

```
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Result addCar(@Validated Car car) {
        carService.addCar(car);
        return Result.ok();
    }
```

When I don't add parameters "price", No response "not null". but "Access Denied". if add the parameters "price" it's ok ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY86C.png)
Who can answer my question? thanks

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you running?

Comment: springboot 3.1.2 and thr org.hibernate.validator is 8.0.1.Final